# What is toLocaleString()?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

According to [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), `toLocaleString` is about converting dates. However, Chrome exposes the function on more than strings. For example:

```
a = function () {};
a.toLocaleString();  // "function () {}"
```

What is the `toLocaleString`? Why is it exposed, for example, on the empty function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's also [available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toLocaleString) on `Object.prototype`, so indirectly on pretty much anything.

For Chrome, you can look at [V8's implementation](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/v8natives.js#233), which doesn't do anything fancy:

```
function ObjectToLocaleString() {
  if (IS_NULL_OR_UNDEFINED(this) && !IS_UNDETECTABLE(this)) {
    throw MakeTypeError("called_on_null_or_undefined",
                        ["Object.prototype.toLocaleString"]);
  }
  return this.toString();  // <-- just calls toString
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what the `%` means in front of various functions calls?

Comment: @Randomblue: It's a call to a C++ runtime function, I believe. Look in `runtime.cc` for the functions. (Disclamier: I've merely been messing around in the codebase, so not sure if I'm correct here.)